# How do I configure a joystick in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: usb, joystick

I have a joystick([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXzuD.png)) with device id

> 0079-0006-DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick

I would like use it in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.
So I tried to install joystick and jscalbrator to confiure the device.

Following commands where used:

```
sudo apt install joystick
```

Tried to test it with

```
 jstest-gtk
```

Output :

```
The program 'jstest-gtk' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt install jstest-gtk
```

I tried to install it.

[Output image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rxrZ.png)

Then

```
sudo apt-get install jscalibrator
```

[Output image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1yi5.png)

I tried antimicro,but got the error : E: Unable to locate package antimicro
And

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

Completed

```
sudo xboxdrv –detach-kernel-driver
```

Error :
-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found

Later used `lsusb` to find my device and got `Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad`
`lsusb -vd 0079:0006`
Output:

[Output image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8nQc.png)

[Output image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT7JE.png)

Then

```
xboxdrv --debug --device-by-id 0079:0006 --type xbox360 --detach-kernel-driver
```

[Output image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snx9m.png)

```
jscal -c /dev/input/js0
```

Output:

[Output image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MalOR.png)

[Output image 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8FUA.png)

I dont know what else to do.

PS:Hope I provided all the necessary information regarding my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me :

```
modprobe -r xpad 
modprobe xpad
```

[image]